# ¿Por que no estan los nombres de paises en el diccionario de la RAE?

Tags: vocabulario, rae, diccionarios

Un día buscando el nombre de un país en el diccionario de la Real Academia Española, me di cuenta que no estaba. Después de seguir buscando, me percate que no estaba el nombre de NINGÚN país. Solamente los gentilicios.

Sin embargo, no encontré ningún sitio donde se justificase esta falta. ¿A que se debe? ¿Se extiende a todos los sustantivos propios?

Ejemplo:

- https://dle.rae.es/Bolivia?m=form
- https://dle.rae.es/paraguay?m=form
- https://dle.rae.es/Alemania?m=form
- https://dle.rae.es/Nueva%20Zelanda?m=form

Comment: Están en el [panhispánico](https://www.rae.es/dpd/ayuda/paises-y-capitales-con-sus-gentilicios).

Comment: A que se debe esta separacion?

Answer (score 1):

Puede hallarlos en;

**Apéndices**

- Modelos de conjugación verbal
- Abreviaturas
- Símbolos alfabetizables
- Símbolos o signos no alfabetizables
- **Países y capitales, con sus gentilicios**

https://www.rae.es/dpd/ayuda/apendices